# How to use json to get individual elements of a JSONArray

Tags: java, arrays, json, url

I'm trying to get the title of songs from users' soundcloud likes but when I transfer the text file to a JSONArray (Doesn't allow me to transfer to JSONObject) I can't seem to find a way to get the individual elements, in this case "title".

```
  try {

            Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader(
                    "/switched this out but do have correct path"));

            JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) obj;

            System.out.println(jsonArray.size());
            System.out.println(jsonArray.iterator());

            System.out.println(jsonArray.get(10));

            Iterator<JSONObject> iterator = jsonArray.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println(iterator.next());
            }          
        } catch (IOException | ParseException e) {
            System.out.println("Something went wrong");
        }
```

Here is the output from jsonArray.get(10), as you can see there are tons of elements involved.

```
{"comment_count":40,"downloadable":false,"release":null,"created_at":"2016\/03\/31 04:41:13 +0000","description":"Other channels you might like...\r\n▶ @XXX\r\n▶ @YourSecret\r\n▶ @Future\r\n\r\nFree Download: http:\/\/dl.aia.ag\/no-will-hudgrove\r\nSpotify: http:\/\/spotify.aia.ag\/1MCU37t\r\niTunes: http:\/\/buy.aia.ag\/1pMeuob\r\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------------\r\nFollow @no-will\r\nhttp:\/\/twitter.com\/noahwilliamson\r\n\r\n♫ Listen on Spotify:\r\nhttp:\/\/aia.ag\/AIA-Spotify\r\n\r\n♫ Support AIA:\r\nhttp:\/\/aia.ag\/AIA-SC\r\nhttp:\/\/aia.ag\/AIA-FB\r\nhttp:\/\/aia.ag\/AIA-YT\r\nhttp:\/\/aia.ag\/AIA-IG\r\nhttp:\/\/aia.ag\/AIA-TW\r\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------------\r\nSubmit music to the email found in the sidebar of the channel info!","original_content_size":10463196,"title":"No Will - Hudgrove","track_type":"original","duration":242909,"video_url":null,"original_format":"mp3","artwork_url":"https:\/\/i1.sndcdn.com\/artworks-000155542480-tbt08v-large.jpg","streamable":true,"tag_list":"Chillwave Chillout Ambient Melodic Instrumental Beats Daydream Sexy \"Free Download\"","release_month":null,"genre":"Chill","release_day":null,"id":256391781,"state":"finished","last_modified":"2016\/04\/28 10:55:20 +0000","label_name":null,"commentable":true,"bpm":null,"favoritings_count":1981,"kind":"track","purchase_url":"http:\/\/dl.aia.ag\/no-will-hudgrove","release_year":null,"key_signature":null,"isrc":null,"sharing":"public","uri":"https:\/\/api.soundcloud.com\/tracks\/256391781","attachments_uri":"https:\/\/api.soundcloud.com\/tracks\/256391781\/attachments","download_count":0,"license":"all-rights-reserved","purchase_title":"Free Download","user_id":74594593,"embeddable_by":"all","waveform_url":"https:\/\/w1.sndcdn.com\/ucn5ZQ0XdvuY_m.png","permalink":"no-will-hudgrove","permalink_url":"http:\/\/soundcloud.com\/chill\/no-will-hudgrove","user":{"avatar_url":"https:\/\/i1.sndcdn.com\/avatars-000199251203-cuua5s-large.jpg","kind":"user","id":74594593,"permalink":"chill","permalink_url":"http:\/\/soundcloud.com\/chill","last_modified":"2016\/05\/02 22:33:11 +0000","uri":"https:\/\/api.soundcloud.com\/users\/74594593","username":"chill"},"label_id":null,"stream_url":"https:\/\/api.soundcloud.com\/tracks\/256391781\/stream","playback_count":6739}
```

I want to get the "title" from objects like that ^^^ any thoughts?

p.s. The iterator loop prints out 39 of the gross objects I pasted above

Comment: Try: `System.out.println(iterator.next().getString("title"));`

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to need a little bit more information for this one.

From what I can tell, the issue is getting the data back out?

It would look something like this:

```
string title = jsonArray["title"].toString();
```

Then the string would be the value of the title.

If this is not the answer you're looking for, then clarify and ask me again.

Comment: My apologies, so i'm using the org.json.simple library and have used a text file containing JSON objects that represent information about songs from soundcloud. I can access each separate song, but can seem to find the way to get the elements within the song objects. For example, the string I posted above has elements like "track_type", "duration", "title", and many more. The iterator loop I use gets the song objets as a whole but I cant access the individual element using the org.json.simple library, the JSONArray doesn't behave like a normal array where you can use ["element name"]

Comment: Have you tried to convert the json array to a java array?

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by making JSONObjects out of each JSONArray element, and then used JSONObjectName.get("elementName")

Answer (score 0):

1) Not sure, but maybe you have some charset issues in your json.

Try this:

```
JSONObject obj = (JSONObject)jsonArray.get(10);
```